# how to hide an image gallery to show just one picture

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I don´t know how to this, I have two sections, in the first one I have some images, the other have a list. I need that when I make a hover on the list :
"li:hover" the images on the other section be hide to show another picture.
My code is this: `

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>prueba</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>
<style>section.names {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  height: 400px;
}

li a:hover>img {
  display: initial;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

section.gallery {
  width: 39%;
  float: left;
  height: 85%;
}</style>
</head>

<body>
<script>$('.item').hover( function() {
  $('.gallery > img').hide();
  $('.gallery > #' + $(this).attr('data-img')).show();
});

$( ".names" ).mouseout(function() {
   $('.gallery > img').show();
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <section class="gallery">
    <img id="img1" src="lizard.jpg" alt="Smiley face 01" height="100%" width="100%">
    <img id="img2" src="lizard.jpg" alt="Smiley face 02" height="100" width="200">
    <img id="img3" src="lizard.jpg" alt="Smiley face 03" height="45px" width="150px">
  </section>

  <section class="names">
    <ol>
      <li class="item" data-img="img1"><a href="project.html">Esplai,silkscreen and editorial production</a></li>
      <li class="item" data-img="img2"><a href="project.html">Esplai,silkscreen and editorial production</a></li>
      <li class="item" data-img="img3"><a href="project.html">Esplai,silkscreen and editorial production</a></li>
    </ol>

  </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually the image appears on the right but I need yo show up on the left, and the other hide.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use some jquery script to simulate this effect, as via `CSS` it is not posible to access the images outside the names section and use `hover` at the same time. Here's a working snippet:

```js
$('.item').hover( function() {
  $('.gallery > img').hide();
  $('.gallery > #' + $(this).attr('data-img')).show();
});

$( ".names" ).mouseout(function() {
   $('.gallery > img').show();
});
```

```css
section.names {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  height: 400px;
}

li a:hover>img {
  display: initial;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

section.gallery {
  width: 39%;
  float: left;
  height: 85%;
}

`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <section class="gallery">
    <img id="img1" src="lizard.jpg" alt="Smiley face 01" height="100%" width="100%">
    <img id="img2" src="lizard.jpg" alt="Smiley face 02" height="100" width="200">
    <img id="img3" src="lizard.jpg" alt="Smiley face 03" height="45px" width="150px">
  </section>

  <section class="names">
    <ol>
      <li class="item" data-img="img1"><a href="project.html">Esplai,silkscreen and editorial production</a></li>
      <li class="item" data-img="img2"><a href="project.html">Esplai,silkscreen and editorial production</a></li>
      <li class="item" data-img="img3"><a href="project.html">Esplai,silkscreen and editorial production</a></li>
    </ol>

  </section>
</div>
```

To do this, first give a `class="item"` to each element list and a custom html5 attribute like `data-img="img01"`. Then, add individual ID's to each image on the left section. Notice that the image ID and the attribute has to be the same in order for this to work.

The script functions is triggered each time the user mouse over the list elements. When the user leaves the list, the left images are displayed again.

***Edit**
Here is an screenshot of how to import the jQuery library:
[image: jquery]

Comment: I'll try your code but does not work for me, I've written the changes on the question

Comment: Does the snippet on my answer reproduce what you are trying to accomplish? The code I posted is using jquery library, be sure you import that using: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: yeah it`s the same

Comment: Then, by just copying and pasting the code should work. Did you tried adding the jQuery link I provided?

Comment: Copy the exact code I posted. The javascript script and html part should look the same. Your answer still does not have the exact code

Comment: Ok now I see it. You should place the jQuery link after the `<script></script>` code. One good practice is to place the jQuery library at bottom of  the page after closing the tag `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com... ></body></html>`

Comment: Ok you`re right, I don't know sometimes works an others not work maybe is the cache, but thanks

Comment: I've added an screenshot for a better explanation of how to import the library in your code